# Fetch values after @ in Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, email, count, pattern-matching, substring

I have a PostgreSQL table customer in which I have two fields : Email and Name. I want to fetch the values after the @ and need the count of these. Please find the image below :

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `SUBSTRING` and `POSITION` :

```
SELECT substring(Email,position('@' in Email) + 1) as email,
       COUNT(*)
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY substring(Email,position('@' in Email) + 1)
```

Comment: I do not want to show '@' value in the email field. I tried with the above query and this is the result I got :             email        count 
                     @aaa.com    2

Comment: I modified your query and now i got the result : SELECT substring(name,position('@' in name)+1) as email,
       COUNT(*)
FROM pgsbizdim.employees
GROUP BY substring(name,position('@' in name)+1)